# TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'b_regularizer')

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook, nlp

Below is the code for my Python Script named NER_model.py
The problem is with the line **self.model.add**, in the function named **make_and_compile**, where one of the input arguments is **b_regularizer**. Did the recent versions of Keras have a different name for 'b_regularizer' ?

Can someone plz tell me how to resolve this error?

```
# Keras imports
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers.wrappers import TimeDistributed
from keras.layers.wrappers import Bidirectional
from keras.layers.core import Dropout
from keras.regularizers import l2
from keras import metrics

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report


class NER():
    def __init__(self, data_reader):
        self.data_reader = data_reader
        self.x, self.y = data_reader.get_data();
        self.model = None
        self.x_train = None
        self.y_train = None
        self.x_test = None
        self.y_test = None

    def make_and_compile(self, units = 150, dropout = 0.2, regul_alpha = 0.0):
        self.model = Sequential()
        # Bidirectional LSTM with 100 outputs/memory units
        self.model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units, 
                                          return_sequences=True,
                                          kernel_regularizer=l2(regul_alpha),
                                          b_regularizer=l2(regul_alpha)),
                                    input_shape = [self.data_reader.max_len, 
                                                   self.data_reader.LEN_WORD_VECTORS]))
        self.model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(self.data_reader.LEN_NAMED_CLASSES, 
                                             activation='softmax',
                                             kernel_regularizer=l2(regul_alpha),
                                             b_regularizer=l2(regul_alpha))))
        self.model.add(Dropout(dropout))
        self.model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                           optimizer='adam',
                           metrics=['accuracy'])
        print(self.model.summary())
```

**And the error is:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\6th SEM - NLP Project\NER_model.py in make_and_compile(self, units, dropout, regul_alpha)
     29                 self.model = Sequential()
     30                 # Bidirectional LSTM with 100 outputs/memory units
---> 31         self.model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units, 
     32                                                                                   return_sequences=True,
     33                                                                                   kernel_regularizer=l2(regul_alpha),

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\layers\recurrent_v2.py in __init__(self, units, activation, recurrent_activation, use_bias, kernel_initializer, recurrent_initializer, bias_initializer, unit_forget_bias, kernel_regularizer, recurrent_regularizer, bias_regularizer, activity_regularizer, kernel_constraint, recurrent_constraint, bias_constraint, dropout, recurrent_dropout, return_sequences, return_state, go_backwards, stateful, time_major, unroll, **kwargs)
   1087     self.return_runtime = kwargs.pop('return_runtime', False)
   1088 
-> 1089     super(LSTM, self).__init__(
   1090         units,
   1091         activation=activation,

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\layers\recurrent.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1135   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
   1136     self._create_non_trackable_mask_cache()
-> 1137     super(DropoutRNNCellMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
   1138 
   1139   @tf.__internal__.tracking.no_automatic_dependency_tracking

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\layers\recurrent.py in __init__(self, units, activation, recurrent_activation, use_bias, kernel_initializer, recurrent_initializer, bias_initializer, unit_forget_bias, kernel_regularizer, recurrent_regularizer, bias_regularizer, activity_regularizer, kernel_constraint, recurrent_constraint, bias_constraint, dropout, recurrent_dropout, return_sequences, return_state, go_backwards, stateful, unroll, **kwargs)
   2816         trainable=kwargs.get('trainable', True),
   2817         **cell_kwargs)
-> 2818     super(LSTM, self).__init__(
   2819         cell,
   2820         return_sequences=return_sequences,

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\layers\recurrent.py in __init__(self, cell, return_sequences, return_state, go_backwards, stateful, unroll, time_major, **kwargs)
    417       kwargs['input_shape'] = input_shape
    418 
--> 419     super(RNN, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    420     self.cell = cell
    421     self.return_sequences = return_sequences

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    627     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    628     try:
--> 629       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    630     finally:
    631       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py in __init__(self, seed, force_generator, **kwargs)
   3436       **kwargs: other keyword arguments that will be passed to the parent class
   3437     """
-> 3438     super().__init__(**kwargs)
   3439     self._random_generator = backend.RandomGenerator(
   3440         seed, force_generator=force_generator)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    627     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    628     try:
--> 629       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    630     finally:
    631       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py in __init__(self, trainable, name, dtype, dynamic, **kwargs)
    339     }
    340     # Validate optional keyword arguments.
--> 341     generic_utils.validate_kwargs(kwargs, allowed_kwargs)
    342 
    343     # Mutable properties

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\utils\generic_utils.py in validate_kwargs(kwargs, allowed_kwargs, error_message)
   1172   for kwarg in kwargs:
   1173     if kwarg not in allowed_kwargs:
-> 1174       raise TypeError(error_message, kwarg)
   1175 
   1176 

TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'b_regularizer')
```

Comment: try `bias_regularizer`

Comment: This changed years ago, always check the documentation: https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/lstm/

Comment: Which `TensorFlow` version and base environment are you using? As this piece of code does not show any error to me when I tried replicating the error using `TF 2.8, 2.7, 2.6` in `Google colab`.

Comment: I am using the '2.8.0' version

Answer (score 1):

Please try again by opening a new jupyter notebook as this code does not show any error when tried replicating the error in the same environment.

***Please check the screenshot below for your reference.***

[image]

Comment: I upgraded TensorFlow from 2.8 to 2.9 and Python from 3.6 to 3.8, and it worked perfectly.